# When does a homeomorphism preserve Cauchy Sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is there any necessary and sufficient condition under which a the inverse function in a homeomorphism will preserve Cauchy Sequence ?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27901/does-cauchy-continuity-imply-uniform-continuity-no You'll find a couple of characterizations there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 'Cauchy sequence' is a term which is usually used in connection with a metric. Since it is known that a topological space (like $\mathbb{R}$) can carry two different metrics which generate the same topologies, for which one makes $\mathbb{R}$ a complete metric space while the other does not, there is not much hope that this can be ever assured. You'd be better off with convergent sequences.

Comment: Therefore this question should be understood in terms of uniform spaces

Comment: @userNaN: The same problem arises: a sequence can be Cauchy with respect to one uniformity generating a topology and not Cauchy with respect to another.

Comment: If you want to speak of Cauchy-stuff you need to fix a uniformity, not the other way round (choose uniformity to fit into the topology).